# Facebook tabs in iPad app

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I was wondering how I can make tabs with images/video/etc., similar to the (old) FBML page tabs, that will show up in the new FB iPad/iPhone app.

I understand I will need to use iFrames to create pages to last past 1/1/12 but how will these new tabs then show up in the iPad/iPhone or other FB app?
Currently none of the FBML pages are showing up in the apps.

Comment: there is some rumor floating around that this feature is coming soon. apparently zynga will be the first to have this, but so far i have not been able to find an example.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special type of link that will force a tab open in iPhone and iPad (within the apps.) It works by forcing the desktop version to open in UI Webview.  I can't find the link information though. Anyone know what I am talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't display page tabs on mobile devices yet, except on iPad when using safari apparently, although I haven't tested that myself.

Comment: OK, clear. 

I checked btw and safari on ipad is showing the FBML pages. 

But do you know if the iFrames pages are showing on the new apps? Cannot find a good example

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but iframe apps should have the same overall behaviour as FBML apps, i.e they should both display on the same devices.